# Blockchain Explorer Fails to query installed chaincodes - Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

Connected the blockchain explorer (https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer) to the Composer channel. All good for the most part, and  I can browse and call API for blocks and transactions, however querying installed chaincodes fails. The stack is below. Any suggestions here? Much appreciated!

=====
`Please open Internet explorer to access ：http://localhost:4000/
[2017-11-19 10:50:07.735] [INFO] Helper - Successfully loaded member from persistence
error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Authorization for GETINSTALLEDCHAINCODES on channel getinstalledchaincodes has been denied with error Failed verifying that proposal's creator satisfies local MSP principal during channelless check policy with policy [Admins]: [This identity is not an admin])
    at /Users/andrei/Development/Zest/Blockchain/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:554:15
error: [Client.js]: Failed Installed Chaincodes Query. Error: Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Authorization for GETINSTALLEDCHAINCODES on channel getinstalledchaincodes has been denied with error Failed verifying that proposal's creator satisfies local MSP principal during channelless check policy with policy [Admins]: [This identity is not an admin])
    at /Users/andrei/Development/Zest/Blockchain/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:554:15
[2017-11-19 10:50:07.764] [ERROR] Query - Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Authorization for GETINSTALLEDCHAINCODES on channel getinstalledchaincodes has been denied with error Failed verifying that proposal's creator satisfies local MSP principal during channelless check policy with policy [Admins]: [This identity is not an admin])
    at /Users/andrei/Development/Zest/Blockchain/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:554:15
[2017-11-19 10:50:08.784] [ERROR] Query - TypeError: Cannot read property 'toArray' of null
    at EC.sign (/Users/andrei/Development/Zest/Blockchain/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/elliptic/lib/elliptic/ec/index.js:102:30)
    at CryptoSuite_ECDSA_AES.sign (/Users/andrei/Development/Zest/Blockchain/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/impl/CryptoSuite_ECDSA_AES.js:267:25)
    at Signer.sign (/Users/andrei/Development/Zest/Blockchain/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/msp/identity.js:167:28)
    at SigningIdentity.sign (/Users/andrei/Development/Zest/Blockchain/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/msp/identity.js:218:23)
    at Object.module.exports.signProposal (/Users/andrei/Development/Zest/Blockchain/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/client-utils.js:116:28)
    at Function.sendTransactionProposal (/Users/andrei/Development/Zest/Blockchain/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Channel.js:1367:37)
    at Client.queryInstalledChaincodes (/Users/andrei/Development/Zest/Blockchain/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Client.js:590:18)
    at helper.getOrgAdmin.then (/Users/andrei/Development/Zest/Blockchain/blockchain-explorer/app/query.js:118:18)
    at <anonymous>`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this Fabric error is that the admin you're using is not recognized by your Fabric CA server (container): did you restart your CA server.

If installed on Linux or Mac  (Windows not supported by Hyperledger Composer as yet FYI) - you could use a local Fabric Blockchain Explorer setup to query Composer business networks installed as follows:

eg (where channel name is `composerchannel` ):

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/apis/chaincodes?channel=composerchannel" -H "accept:application/json"
```

will return the current list of composer business networks installed on that channel.

or list of chaincodes deployed:

```
curl -X POST  http://localhost:8080/chaincodelist -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'content-type: application/json' -d ''
```

Comment: restarted the CA. Same error curling the API: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toArray' of null
    at EC.sign (/Users/andrei/Development/Zest/Blockchain/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/elliptic/lib/elliptic/ec/index.js:102:30)
    at CryptoSuite_ECDSA_AES.sign..